# Snowflake stored procedure conditional force error

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want the procedure to fail in case of any conditions been met.

Is there a way to conditionally exit the Snowflake stored procedure with error.

Answer (score 1):

**[RAISE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/raise.html)** could be used.

> Raises an exception.

```
-- Stored Procedure - Snowflake Scripting
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc(ARG INT)
RETURNS INT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
DECLARE
   my_exception EXCEPTION (-20002, 'Raised MY_EXCEPTION.');
BEGIN
   IF (ARG = 2) THEN
        RAISE my_exception;
   END IF;
   
   RETURN ARG;        
END;
```

Test:

```
CALL test_proc(1);
-- 1

CALL test_proc(2);
-- -20002 (P0001): Uncaught exception of type 'MY_EXCEPTION' on line 5 at position 8:
-- Raised MY_EXCEPTION.
```