# Raising exception in others on Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm migrating some stored procedures from Oracle to Snowflake and I need to raise an exception in others segment of exception on snowflake exception including a column from cursor. Here is an example from oracle:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE        sp 
AS
CURSOR SCGR
  IS
    SELECT SP.REQUEST_NUM,
…
    from table;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN SCGR
  LOOP
    BEGIN      
          INSERT
          INTO table(…)
  VALUES
            (…);
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'An error was encountered in CUST_GROUP_REQUEST insert for - '||I.REQUEST_NUM||' - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
          EXIT;
        END;
      
END;
```

With this part I'm having troubles in Snowflake:

```
EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
              RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001,'An error was encountered in CUST_GROUP_REQUEST insert for - '||I.REQUEST_NUM||' - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
              EXIT;
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Looks like a duplkicate of: [Snowflake stored procedure conditional force error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70792287/5070879). Snowflake has **RAISE** syntax for such cases.

Comment: But I can't put ||I.REQUEST_NUM||' - '||SQLCODE|| in exception declaration...

Answer (score 2):

If you check the RAISE command, you will see that it accepts an exception name, not a string expression which you can build dynamically.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/snowflake-scripting/raise.html

Do you really need to raise an exception, or want to return a result cotaining the exception details?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/exceptions.html?_ga=2.186509665.956198205.1648142906-1409600040.1607023304#handling-an-exception

```
return object_construct('Error type', 'Other error',
                        'SQLCODE', sqlcode,
                        'SQLERRM', sqlerrm,
                        'SQLSTATE', sqlstate);
```

Comment: I have a similar use case and instead of returning I want to raise an exception and break the execution, it is helpful in multi-statement scripts.